# Issue with jquery remove method on IE7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table class="myCustomers">
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <ul id="salesCustomers">
       <li title="cust 1"><a id="cust_1" >customer 1</a></li>
       <li title="cust 2"></li>
       </ul>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
```

when i do on below on IE 7, DOM element corresponding to "customer 1" gets removed from container "salesCustomers" but
"salesCustomers"  container does get adjusted(i mean IE 7 displays empty space in place of it) after removal of element

```
  $('#cust_1').remove();
```

It works fine on IE8,9,firefox,chrome but not on IE 7?

**Updated:-**

CSS part is

```css
table.myCustomers li {
    margin: 8px;
}

table.myCustomers li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a {
    color: #000000;
    margin: 3px;
}
```

Comment: you need to share the related css also

Comment: ""salesCustomers" container does get adjusted" ... did you mean "salesCustomers" does *not* get adjusted? Meaning there is still a blank space where it formerly was, instead of cust2 moving up?

Comment: Set up an example on jsfiddle if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty space may be since the `li` is still there. (as pointed out by Jayraj)

If you want to remove the `li` corresponding to the `#cust_1` as well,

You have a couple of ways to do it,

1. `$("[title='cust 1']").remove();`
2. `$("#cust_1").parents("li").remove(); //this will remove the
   child element as well`

[Test link](http://jsfiddle.net/WgPYa/)

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
  $('#cust_1').remove();
```

will only remove the tag `<a id='cust1'>customer1</a>` tag. Its surrounding `<li>` tag is still in the DOM. If your CSS has assigned some height to `<li>` elements, it will still appear as an empty space.

Comment: Is there a way i can remove parent li also alongwith element a?